# Handling nested input-types with type-graphql and typegoose

Tags: node.js, typescript, typegraphql, typegoose

I'm using `typegoose` with `type-graphql` and when I try to use nested `@InputType()`, the nested object gets converted into `mongoose.Types.ObjectId()`. How do I handle nested InputTypes

This is my code (`GrandChild` is not a mongoose document, it's a simple object-type)

```
@ObjectType()
export class GrandChild {
  @Field()
  name: string;
}

@ObjectType()
export class Child {
  @prop()
  @Field()
  name: string;

  @prop({ type: () => GrandChild })
  @Field(() => GrandChild)
  grandChild: GrandChild;
}

@ObjectType()
export class Parent {
  @prop()
  @Field()
  name: string;

  @prop({ ref: Child })
  @Field(() => Child)
  child: Ref<Child>;
}

@InputType()
export class GrandChildInput {
  @Field()
  name: string;
}

@InputType()
export class ChildInput {
  @Field()
  name: string;

  @Field(() => GrandChild)
  grandChild: GrandChildInput;
}

@InputType()
export class Parent {
  @Field()
  name: string;

  @Field(() => Child)
  child: ChildInput;
}
```

---

Example input:

```json
{
  "name": "Parent A",
  "child": {
    "name": "Child A",
    "grandChild": {
      "name": "GrandChild A"
    }
  }
}
```

`parent` query:

```
{
  parent {
    name
    child {
      name
      grandChild {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the `parent` query, I get the following output

```sh
Cannot read property "Child.grandChild" of undefined.
```

I used mongo bash to get the parent document and this is what I got:

db.parent.find():

```json
{
  name: "Parent A",
  child: ObjectId("some-object-id-here")
}
```

db.child.find():

```json
{
  name: "Child A",
  grandChild: {
    _id: ObjectId("some-object-id-here")
  }  // <-- This is not supposed to be a document
}
```

How do fix this?

Answer (score 0):

this question was also asked on discord, which came to the conclusion that the provided output was not right, and after finding the the actual data was:

```json
{
  name: "Child A",
  grandChild: {
    _id: ObjectId("some-object-id-here")
  }
}
```

then the issue was clear: class `GrandChild` didnt have any `@prop` on properties
(this was known from the beginning, but what was investigated was why it was `grandChild: ObjectId("some-object-id-here")` instead of `grandChild: { _id: ObjectId("some-object-id-here") }`)

Comment: I tried using `@prop` decorator on both my input type and object type but the grand-child document still has just the _id field.

Comment: if you use transpile to file and then run it, did you already try clearing your build? otherwise i have no idea what else could be the problem with this

Comment: I've removed the nested object for the time being. Not sure if this is an issue with Typegoose or Type GraphQL. Thanks for the help!